# Como modificar el valor de una variable global desde Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Por ejemplo, necesito cambiar el valor de la variable **existUser** que por defecto esta inicializada como **false** a **true** pero al finalizar la variable sigue estando en **false** y solo se mantiene el valor **true** dentro del response de Alamofire

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire


class UserLoginModel {

let URL_PRODUCCION = "url-de-mi-servidor"

var username: String
var userpassword: String
var usercompany: String

var existUser: Bool?

init(username: String, userpassword: String, usercompany: String){
    self.username = username
    self.userpassword = userpassword
    self.usercompany = usercompany
}

func test(){

    let url = "\(URL_PRODUCCION)"

    let parametros: Parameters = [
        "password":"\(self.password!)",
        "username":"\(self.user!)"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parametros) .responseJSON {
        response in

        if let JSON = response.result.value{
            self.existUser = true
        }else{
            self.existUser = false
        }
    }
}


func setExistUser(existUser: Bool){
    self.existUser = existUser
}

func getExistUser(){
    return self.existUser
}
```

}

Desde el controlador creo un objeto de tipo UserLoginModel, luego llamo al metodo **test()**, después llamo al método **getExistUser()**, pero me da error y dice **existUser** es igual a **nil**.

En fin, no he podido asignar un valor desde dentro de **Alamofire** ni siquiera con el método **setUserExist()**, espero que ahora tengas una día más clara y me puedas ayudar, de antemano muchas gracias.

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var user: String?
var password: String?
var company: String?

var usuario: UserLoginModel?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func btnIngresarClick(_ sender: Any) {

    self.user = textFieldUserName.text!
    self.password = textFieldUserPassword.text!
    self.company = textFieldUserCompany.text!

    self.usuario = UserLoginModel(username: self.user!, userpassword: self.password!, usercompany: self.company!)
    self.usuario?.test()


    if(self.usuario?.getExistUser()){
        //Haga esto
    }else{
        //Haga esto otro

        //Siempre está entrando por aquí, si 'existUser' la inicializo en 'false' siempre me devuelve 'false',
        //pero sí la dejo como un 'optional' siempre me retorna 'nil'
    }

}
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar desde donde viene la variable `existUser`? Es muy probable que no esté entrando al if `let JSON = response.result.value`

Comment: La variable **existUser** la tengo de forma global de la siguiente manera:

class UserModel{

var existUser: Bool?

func test(){

    let url = "\(URL_PRODUCCION)"

    let parametros: Parameters = [
        "password":"\(self.password!)",
        "username":"\(self.user!)"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parametros) .responseJSON {
        response in

        if let JSON = response.result.value{
            self.existUser = true
        }else{
            self.existUser = false
        }
    }
 }
}

Comment: La variable **existUser** la tengo de manera global

class UserLogin{
    var existUser: Bool?

    func test(){
        ...
    }

}

Comment: Está entrando al if con la condición `let JSON = response.result.value`?

Comment: Si, entra al if pero el valor de existUser solo se mantiene dentro del .responseJSON, no puedo asignarlo a la variable que está por fuera.

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y postear toda tu clase? (con bien formato igualmente)

Comment: Muchas gracias, dame un minuto y edito la pregunta.

Comment: @FelipePeña ya modifique la pregunta y así está estructurada la clase, gracias por el interes en ayudar.

Comment: Primero, dices en el enunciado que se inicializa con `false` pero es un optional, así que por defecto es `nil`. Puedes colocar un ejemplo de instancias la clase?

Comment: Es que anteriormente lo tenia inicializado en **false** pero  cuando accedo a su valor con el metodo **getExistUser** siempre me retorna **false** y ese valor no cambia cuando entra a realizar la petición con **Alamofire**.

Comment: @FelipePeña editaré la publicación y colocaré el ejemplo más abajo.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que la llamada que haces asincrónica, o sea, al momento en que llamas a `if(self.usuario?.getExistUser()){` la llamada al servidor que usas con Alamofire puede estar todavía corriendo, sin obtener respuesta y por ende, el valor de `existUser` es `false` aún.

Lo que te recomiendo, es que al método `test` le des como parámetro de entrada un bloque que corra dentro del éxito de la llamada de Alamofire.

Algo así como:

`func test(completionBlock: (Bool) -> ())`

Después lo debería llamar:

`self.usuario?.test(completionBlock: (success) {
//Agregas tu lógica donde ya tienes la respuesta de Alamofire
})`

Por último, dentro del éxito de Alamofire llamas al bloque con la misma variable del modelo u otra que consideres pertinente:

`if let JSON = response.result.value {
    self.existUser = true
    completionBlock(self.existUser)
} else{
    self.existUser = false
    completionBlock(self.existUser)
}`

Ojalá sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias, he estado averiguando y he encontrado respuesta muy parecidas a la que me acabas de dar, con la diferencia que lo hacen con algo llamado **completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> ()** en realidad no sé si sea lo mismo, pero la forma en que explicaste me parece mucho más clara y sencilla, estaré realizando pruebas y me quedaré con la que me resulte mucho más fácil.
Muchas gracias, me ha servido de mucho.

Comment: Es exactamente lo mismo. Usar el `@escaping` es más seguro incluso.

Comment: Vale Felipe, muchas gracias por la aclaración, ha sido de gran ayuda, le debo una.